# Typescript union and intersection give unintuitive and wrong error messages

Tags: typescript, interface, union-types, intersection-types

This exported type validates everything perfectly, but gives wrong validation error:

```js
export type Animal = RequireSwimOrFly & RequireColorOrSizeOrVolume & (CantHaveBothColorOrSize | CanHaveNeitherColorOrSize)

const myAnimal: Animal = {
swim: "greatly",
color: "yellow",
size: "large",
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
Property 'fly' is missing in type '{ swim: string; color: string; size: string; }' but required in type 'Required<Pick<IAnimal, "fly">>'.(2322)
```

But that's not the correct validation! It's acceptable to NOT have fly, because it has swim. The true error is having color and size at the same time. Any way to give more intuitive errors for future developers?

[Here's a working version on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgZQO7ILYHlUAxAGxCgF5YEV0BBYAGQgEMBnYfAOwgB4BJOlzwsSAGigByNjlySoAHykAzMpIB8AWABQoSNSRoIAYQD2JU6kIZkALwiEAaucS5oVOIfpNWHbn0FhXFEJSQBjc0t5JWk7CGipADcXNw0dPWhjFi5gAAkWRIgAIVNgAAszCytUG3tKA1oHLjJ-ASERcSkIqoTY+zTdcEzs-MKAOQhkcohUSstrOPr8XCm2oJCuyNRetjiNKAAyKABvKG7LAH4ALigeQtQJXftr24h7qABfHXShhqMGZjsTg8XgAFQkAGkICA2FAIAAPYAQLgAE1hAGtoaZlFBQfVMSBsbj1JQdFByVAAArIMLosESACi8LCJEQKL4BKJ4KgUJh6i02gphxOZKFFIA2hCoMguDzoWwALoAWhenkaKN41Np9J5-OFlJYqGAyFEmppdO5TJZbL4vLYkP5AqFH0l8oV30G+jVRm4LRB3LtcMRyLRUE5OLxVHDxNJgopWotjOZrPZvGjAfl-NF5KOx2zYsl0tlduVqpoRg1CZ1EL1RwNRpNJF4cAiqA1VpTtvlDokiFREGUMogKKzcfJLpLHplSNQyhYYWggQ6IrHUBkeBeHFQMoA5gBufOqECb4Dbrj7-PnVAns8X1dPCA33cH1fJVluJ-nl9fbQ6BFgSxgCgDIoHaYISHqb10GwPBCFIcgjigkwtgWewnBSaAjgACiyHJRmKUoKhQmpFiUXD8ImKYyhmOZqlqCAAEoPQiLgOCgXAQDA0Qbi4iCqDzbR11wG4ACId3QFhgDIESxB0K9RJACASAsLAZJ0B9RJIQ0dwgNTtB-IA)

I am using multiple types to check multiple conditions:

```js
type RequireSwimOrFly = RequireAtLeastOne<IAnimal, 'swim' | 'fly'>
type RequireColorOrSizeOrVolume = RequireAtLeastOne<IAnimal, 'color' | 'size' | 'volume'>
type CantHaveBothColorOrSize = RequireOnlyOne<IAnimal, 'color' | 'size'>
type CanHaveNeitherColorOrSize = Omit<IAnimal, 'color' | 'size'> & { color?: never, size?: never }
```

With the requires defined as follow:

```js
type RequireAtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>
    }[Keys]

type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>
    }[Keys]
```

And the interface:

```js
interface IAnimal {
    swim?: string;
    fly?: string;
    color?: string;
    size?: string;
    volume?: string;
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce this down to a more *minimal* [mre]?  Also, I might agree that the error messages are "unintuitive", but "wrong" has not been demonstrated.  Ultimately your `Animal` type is a [huge awful union](https://tsplay.dev/wXjo9m), and if you assign a value that matches *none* of those, the compiler is free to pick whichever one it wants in the error message. ...

Comment: ... It's not "wrong" for the compiler not to pick the one "closest" to the thing you've given it. If I ask you for a chocolate chip cookie or a cheeseburger and you give me a plain hamburger, I can say "this isn't a cookie, there are no chocolate chips".

Comment: Ultimately I'd say this is just a limitation of TS, as per [ms/TS#4451](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4451).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to reduze this. What I ultimately needed is given parameters A,B,C,D,E it must have require at least one between <A, B>, at least one between <C,D,E>  and either both or none <C,D>.  My solution works but it does not gives clear error. Is there a way I can improve this and make it less awful? Any tips appreciated! I can reword the question too. Edit: I removed extra parameters from the interface

Comment: I think [ms/TS#4451](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4451) implies that you're not going to get the error message you want with a single union type.  Maybe instead of having a single type, you make a helper function that asks for pieces of the thing you want and then assembles it, so the error is in part of the function.  But that would be a significant refactor and frankly out of scope for the question.  As asked, the answer to this question is "the error message is unintuitive but not wrong", with a link to the relevant GitHub issue.  Shall I write that up or not?

Comment: The issue you linked answer my questions, alright. I will try to do this validation in another way entirely. Thanks @jcalz

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately your `Animal` type is a large [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types; the [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) tend to be distributed over the unions and an intersection of object types can generally be collapsed together.  You can even write a helper "identity" utility type to make that happen explicitly when you view it with IntelliSense:

```
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;

export type Animal = Id<RequireSwimOrFly & RequireColorOrSizeOrVolume & (
    CantHaveBothColorOrSize | CanHaveNeitherColorOrSize
)>
```

which gives you this:

```
/* type Animal = {
    color: string; size?: undefined; volume?: string | undefined;
    swim: string; fly?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color?: undefined; size: string; volume?: string | undefined;
    swim: string; fly?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color: string; size?: undefined; volume: string;
    swim: string; fly?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color?: undefined; size: string; volume: 
    string; swim: string; fly?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color?: undefined; size?: undefined; volume: string;
    swim: string; fly?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color: string; size?: undefined; volume?: string | undefined;
    fly: string; swim?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color?: undefined; size: string; volume?: string | undefined;
    fly: string; swim?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color: string; size?: undefined; volume: string;
    fly: string; swim?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color?: undefined; size: string; volume: string;
    fly: string; swim?: string | undefined;
} | {
    color?: undefined; size?: undefined; volume: string;
    fly: string; swim?: string | undefined;
} */
```

---

If you give the compiler a value which is *not* of type `Animal`, that means it is not assignable to *any* of the members of the union.  It fails each and every one.  A full reporting of why that value is inappropriate would be very, very long, as the compiler mentions each member of the union and how your value fails to match it.  Something like:

```
const myAnimal: Animal = { swim: "greatly", color: "yellow", size: "large", } // error!
/* Type { swim: string; color: string; size: string; } is not assignable to Animal.
 - It can't be a { ✂ 1st union member ✂ } because its 'size' property is 'string' and not 'undefined'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 2nd union member ✂ } because its 'color' property is 'string' and not 'undefined'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 3rd union member ✂ } because its 'size' property is 'string' and not 'undefined'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 4th union member ✂ } because its 'color' property is 'string' and not 'undefined'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 5th union member ✂ } because its 'size' property is 'string' and not 'undefined'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 6th union member ✂ } because its 'fly' property is 'undefined' and not 'string'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 7th union member ✂ } because its 'fly' property is 'undefined' and not 'string'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 8th union member ✂ } because its 'fly' property is 'undefined' and not 'string'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 9th union member ✂ } because its 'fly' property is 'undefined' and not 'string'
 - It can't be a { ✂ 10th union member ✂ } because its 'fly' property is 'undefined' and not 'string'
*/
```

Some unions have thousands of members, so it is not realistic for the compiler to give a full accounting of all the ways in which a value fails to be assignable to it.  It has to do something else.

Now, it *could* try to find "the closest" member of the union to the value according to some metric, and then report only an error there.  Or maybe it could try to find "the most common" reason for failure and report that.  Or maybe it could do some other more human-friendly heuristic.  But it doesn't do any of those things; it picks the last member in the union, and reports that one:

```
const myAnimal: Animal = { swim: "greatly", color: "yellow", size: "large", } // error!
/* Type '{ swim: string; color: string; size: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Animal'.
  It is missing the following properties from type '{ ✂ 10th union member ✂ }' : volume, fly */
```

This message is not *wrong*. It's just not particularly illuminating or intuitive.

---

There was a GitHub issue filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#4451](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4451) asking for something better, but it was closed as "Won't Fix", with the [main explanatory comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4451#issuecomment-134759908) being that it wouldn't be obvious how to write a good algorithm here.

So that's, unfortunately, how it is.  You get some error message that correctly explains part of the reason why your value is bad, but not necessarily "the" reason a clever human being might give.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgZQO7ILYHlUAxAGxCgF5YEV0BBYAGQgEMBnYfAOwgB4BJOlzwsSAGigByNjlySoAHykAzMpIB8AWABQoSNSRoIAYQD2JU6kIZkALwiEAaucS5oVOIfpNWHbn0FhXFEJSQBjc0t5JWk7CGipADcXNw0dPWhjFi5gAAkWRIgAIVNgAAszCytUG3tKA1oHLjJ-ASERcSkIqoTY+zTdcEzs-MKAOQhkcohUSstrOPr8XCm2oJCuyNRetjiNKAAyKABvKG7LAH4ALigeQtQJXftr24h7qABfHXShhqMGZjsTg8XgAFQkAGkICA2FAIAAPYAQLgAE1hAGtoaZlFBQfVMSBsbj1JQdFByVAAArIMLosESACi8LCJEQKL4BKJ4KgUJh6i02gphxOZKFFIA2hCoMguDzoWwALoAWhenkaKN41Np9J5-OFlJYqGAyFEmppdO5TJZbL4vLYkP5AqFH0l8oV30G+jVRm4LRB3LtcMRyLRUE5OLxVHDxNJgopWotjOZrPZvGjAfl-NF5KOx2zYsl0tlduVqpoRg1CZ1EL1RwNRpNJF4cAiqA1VpTtvlDokiFREGUMogKKzcfJLpLHplSNQyhYYWggQ6IrHUBkeBeHFQMoA5gBufOqECb4Dbrj7-PnVAns8X1dPCA33cH1fJVluJ-nl9fbQ-fT8DVQRJKg8QRJFUVhGVlBmKAAFUoAuE4oELGUwyxHFYIVG5YMlBVPigG47hmF8dARMBLGAKAMigdpghIeoAObct0GwPBCFIcgjm9dA5mqWoHFQZx32gI4AAp8yyHJRmKUoKi2BY6iUSTpImKYyhmXiFIgHQAEoBR0AB6AAqKjflo0R6lOAyDKgABGS8thuLdnzXOIXj7dlBx4FE9ygN9XEfJzT13RQoA8gchx8qB83XXAgtvXyj0-HdQvCrzh2-UKrJsgAmByqnc-t0qih94pc-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-YAr8rzyE-qYb+oBpSvwAUPJBA9KJgIJhAwUK815nBgVguBpxD79TbMgs+4c0FXxvvhbBuDpT4P-nsD+X8ZhkL-tIG6gDqGgPAZA5hG8uBbzYUPeBm1yg8NQeg6+mDhFP1EQQrYRCpE-3If-eRVDgE0KkMoxhUCWHqNgVojh71dEn14RfARRiIAPxMS-cR-RJEkOkb-ChtigEgNoU4qATDoFuM0XvTxKNvHCF8fwjBQjAk4OCWIyQR4LERKsbI8Bdi4k2NvAwxJLi1EaJ3h4wRNNMkoL4QYwRd98kiJCcUtQ4TSFRMcfQqpDi5G1JUckpp7DBFC3adkrpASgl4NfiUoZkTrF0MZgo+xoCAHTNcbMlph9NaLP0f4vJqzTEqEGcQ4Z2zKmxImYc5xqjWHNLSYI22FzOlXJ6Tc-pGyHlbIqWMl5Bz5E6ADh6YyuJfiSDbldL2vlO6opLj3eQf8HHD2QKPCeU8qKz2opIKOkgl5xhbvoJF8c4od0cl3I6WLrErDYLsaq0wWrmELiFUFDYICwmUHXXApl9CilpVeL6T1frSoOjLDFCsMU+1lo9A6Hw6kEUNgFCQR4oAByAA)